# 'help' command is not working in my windows powershell

Tags: powershell

So I typed the command 'help' in windows Powershell but I'm getting the following error:

```
more.com : The term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:9 char:19
+ } else { $input | more.com }
+                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (more.com:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Check to see if that that file `more.com` is really missing.  It should be located in your \Windows\System32 folder.  As a temporary work-around you can use `Get-Help` in place of `help`.

Comment: Try using Get-help with the -showwindow switch. This gives you a scrollable window, no need for MORE and it's searchable.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I had to setthe path variable of System32. Thanks :)